# Nginx Redict without modifying url

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I want to make a redirection from one domain to another but from one page only.

Example:
https://domainA.com/site/page to https://domainB.com/site/page

In nginx I put:

```
location /site {
         rewrite ^/site/page https://domainB.com/site/page break;
}
```

and it works, it does the rediction, but it changes the url and I want the url to always be https://domainA.com/site/page

How can I do so that the url does not change?

thank you!

Comment: It's not the same domain, it's different.

Comment: I found the solution with "proxy_ssl_server_name on;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

```
location /site/ {
         proxy_ssl_server_name on;
         proxy_pass https://domainB.com/site/page;
}
```